# Insert data in loop in cql

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to insert a large amount of data into a table in cassandra using the cqlsh.
Is there anything in the language that is similar to(from mongo shell):

```
for(var j=0; j<100000; j++) {
  db.table1.insert({num: i, text: "txt"});
}
```

The batch and apply is not helpful because I want to generate data randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there are no loop in CQL. If you want to mass insert data in Cassandra, you have to use and external tool or language.

Or if you have data in a CSV file, you can also use `COPY` command to load data in a table.